# /bin/sh: 1: /go/src/test.sh: not found

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I am trying to build this dockerfile, the file is copied successfully but I keep getting the following error:

`docker build --no-cache=true -f Dockerfile-Gobase .`

> Sending build
>   context to Docker daemon     34MB
>
> Step 1/3 : FROM golang:1.11.2  ---> df6ac9d1bf64
>
> Step 2/3 : COPY ./test.sh /go/src/  ---> 38a538f0289d
>
> Step 3/3 : RUN (ls -l /go/src/ && cd /go/src/ && /go/src/test.sh) 
>   ---> Running in 089de53d11f0
>
> total 4
>
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34 Jan 24 03:22 test.sh
>
> /bin/sh: 1: /go/src/test.sh: not found
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c (ls -l /go/src/ && cd /go/src/ &&
>   /go/src/test.sh)' returned a non-zero code: 127

These are the file codes

**Dockerfile-Gobase**

```
FROM golang:1.11.2
COPY ./test.sh /go/src/
RUN (ls -l /go/src/ && cd /go/src/ && /go/src/test.sh)
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```

Comment: Check for windows linefeeds in the script. You need to convert those to the Linux linefeed.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much!

Comment: As a side bar, you don't need to place your `RUN` command in parenthesis, you can just execute them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You eliminated the first cause by checking that the script exists in the container with an `ls`. This also eliminated Linux file permissions.

Next possible cause is that your interpreter isn't in the container, but showing the script we see that it's `#!/bin/sh`. And `/bin/sh` is included with your base image.

What's left that I can think of are windows line feeds in the file, a missing library somewhere, or perhaps security tools like SE Linux/AppArmor with a strict configuration. In this case, it looks like windows line feeds were there cause. You just need to configure your editor to output with Linux style line feeds. Otherwise Linux is looking for `/bin/sh\R` to run (where `\R` is the carriage return), and that command does not exist.

This is included in my [DockerCon 18 talk](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/dc2018/faq-stackoverflow-lightning.html#30) which includes lots of other tips you may find useful when starting out.